# cycle2.js fireing before dom elements are loaded via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, tumblr, jquery-cycle2

I've been using tumblr's v1 json api to fetch images from posts, and I have this part working well. However Im not able to trigger the cycle 2 plugin, once these images have been placed into the dom - it appears to be firing too soon.

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/orionrush/9XEw2/

Given my examples can anyone point me in the right direction as to why this isn't working?
Many thanks

In short I fetch the images and place them into the dom with the following:

```
var Tumblr = Tumblr || {};
Tumblr.RecentPhotos = function(el, postsCount, tagged) {
  var apiUrl = "http://2014frames.tumblr.com/api/read/json?callback=?&filter=text&type=photo&num=" + (postsCount || 10) + "&tagged=" + tagged;  
//var apiUrl = "http://" + document.domain + "/api/read/json?callback=?&filter=text&type=photo&num=" + (postsCount || 10)+ "&tagged=" + tagged;

  var renderPosts = function(posts) {
    return $.map($.map(posts, postInfo), renderPost);
  };

  var renderPost = function(post) {
  //return "<div><a href='" + post.url + "' ><img src='" + post.src + "' width='500' data-cycle-title='"+ post.title + "' /><div class='cycle-overlay'>" + post.title + "</div></a></div>";
  return "<div><img src='" + post.src + "' width='100%' data-cycle-title='"+ post.title + "' /><div class='cycle-overlay'>" + post.title + "</div></div>";

  }; 
  var postInfo = function(post) {
  console.log(post.photos[0]);
      return {
        title: post.photos[0]['caption'],
        url: post["url"],
        height: post.photos[0]['height'],
        src: post.photos[0]['photo-url-500']
      };
  };
  return {
    render: function() {
      $.getJSON(apiUrl, function(data) {
        $("<div class='cycle-slideshow composite-example' data-cycle-fx=fadeout data-cycle-timeout=0 data-cycle-loader=wait data-cycle-auto-height=container data-cycle-slides='> div' >").appendTo($(el)).append(renderPosts(data.posts).join("\n"));
      });
      return this;
    }
  }
};
```

And then trigger it all with the following:

```
jQuery(function() { new Tumblr.RecentPhotos(jQuery(".slideshow"),10 ,"news").render(), function(){$(".cycle-slideshow").cycle();} });
```

Comment: I'm going to play with this, now, but I caution against using V1 of the API because Tumblr staff/support have repeatedly stated that it will eventually cease to be.

Comment: I hear you about the API, but as you can tell Im quite new with JSON etc, and the new api has additional layers of complexity. Since I put this post up, those running the website had changed slightly the way they are posting, so single images hadn't even come up yet.

Answer (score 0):

It needs some work, but I believe I've identified your main problem: if there is only one photo, the array `photos` is empty and you'll need to get your information about the photo from elsewhere in the object.

See my altered JS Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/69Zd2/).

Comment: Ally, you've solved a problem that I han't even encountered yet! Thanks so much for that. Im still stuck however with my original problem of not being able to instantiate the slide show. :/

Comment: So I've figured out how to instantiate cycle, by chaining to the end of the join call in the render function. Im not happy about how cycle is 'baked' into this script, I would really like to be able to fire it with a callback afterward, but for now this is fine.

Answer (score 0):

So I did find a solution to triggering the slideshow, after it was dynamically added to the DOM. Try as I might I never did find a way to fire the slideshow after the elements were added to the DOM, *from within the same script*. My solution may not have the lowest overhead, but I found the simplest way was to create a second script that simply checked for the new DOM elements every half second, and then fired the slided show once they were in place.

That trigger looks something like this:

```
  setTimeout(function trigger() {
    if ($('.cycle-slideshow').length) {
        $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle({
            timeout: 6000,
            fx: 'fadeout',
            random: true,
            pauseOnHover: true,
            autoHeight: 'calc'
        });
        } else {
            // keep trying until the slideshow elements are added to DOM
            setTimeout(trigger, 50); 
        }
      }, 50);
  });
```

my working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/orionrush/pAMLM/

I would love to see other methods, but this is a working solution.